# transition of div causes inner divs to behave weirdly

Tags: html, css

I'm making a div that when you hover on, opens to the right to expose more details.
The problem is when I try to add a transition, my div height grows bigger then grows smaller to match the desired height, any way I can get rid of the height changing?

I've tried adding two div next to each other instead of putting them both in a div parent, problem was to get them match height without using fixed sizes like px.

This is the html:

```css
.ProductContainer {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: left;
  transition:width 0.5s;
}

.ProductDiv {
  margin: 1.5%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  transition:width 0.5s;
}

.ProductImage {
 width:80%;
 margin:10%;
 float:left;
 
 
}

.ProductName {
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#302465;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-top:2%;
 margin-bottom:10%;
 
}

.ProductDiv:hover {
  width: 40%;
}

.ProductDiv:hover .ProductContainer {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class=ProductDiv>
  <div class=ProductContainer>
    <img src=https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/2089/files/placeholder-images-image_large.png?v=1530129081 alt=Img class=ProductImage>
    <div class=ProductName>Fork</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: created a code snippet. can you please tell what is the problem

Comment: what the problem with your code?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Because this Xenio's snippet works well in my Firefox on Mac. It could be the `float` that is messing things up for you. I never use float nowadays, unless I need to have text floating around an image in an a text block.

Comment: I am using google chrome, and i just fixed the snippet to show my issue

Comment: Also, add what you're doing a transition on, otherwise the browser will loop through all the variables that can be animated, and that can lead to a heavy calculation in the end. `transition: width 0.5s` (linear is the default animation timing function and isn't needed).

Comment: Ok will do, thanks for the note

Comment: So you want to decrease the size of the image while increase the width of the container? The problem is that you're using percentage. Use pixels or rem instead. What I suppose is happening is that the image is based on the _percentage_ of the container width, but the image will animate to the container's end value, not the current one in the animation. Hence getting a bigger size before increasing.

Comment: I can't use pixels, because this is a responsive website, but i don't know what is rem?

Comment: It's like `em` but for the whole document (root element). So when you change font size in the `body` element, for example from 16px to 14px, all `rem` units will change with it. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: I tried rem, it gives out the same result

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ProductDiv {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  padding: 10px
}

.ProductImage {
  width: 95px;
}

.ProductDiv:hover {
    width: 400px;
}

.ProductDiv:hover .ProductImage {
    width: 95px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class=ProductDiv>
  <div class=ProductContainer>
    <img src=https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/2089/files/placeholder-images-image_large.png?v=1530129081 alt=Img class=ProductImage>
    <div class=ProductName>Fork</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this solution will help

Comment: I can't use fixed sizes (aka pixels) because this is a responsive wbsite. i need the sizes to be in %

Comment: You shouldn't use percentage to make it responsive, IMHO. You should use rem and then change the font size through media queries. Any other resolution problems should be fixed through media queries.

Comment: If you use percentage it'll adjust according to the screen width, better use pixel and if you want to change the width on devices use media query